# Default Text not displayed in Chosen (JQuery) DropDownList

Tags: razor, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) JQuery Plugin for a ASP.NET MVC (Razor) Project. For a Dropdownlist it does not display the Default Text value set by `data_placeholder`, instead it displays the First Item of the list.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("AuthorId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AuthorId, new
    {
        @class = "chzn-dropdown",
        data_placeholder = "Select Author...",
        style = "width:270px;"
    })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
</div>
```

How to display the default Text for the Dropdown list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is on chosen website

> **Note**: on single selects, the first element is assumed to be selected by the browser. To take advantage of the default text support, you will need to include a blank option as the first element of your select list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I didn't see it on the web site :)